# How to check font text on Flutter golden test

Tags: testing, flutter

I'm making a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/mongol) for vertical Mongolian text. I have a custom widget that needs a special font to display. I'm trying to write a test that shows the Mongolian text has rendered correctly.

On the emulator it looks like this:

[image]

But the golden file looks like this:

[image]

I can't verify that the Mongolian is getting rendered correctly if the golden test is just giving me tofu.

This is my test:

```
testWidgets('MongolText renders font', (WidgetTester tester) async {

  await tester.pumpWidget(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My App')),
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: MongolText('ᠮᠣᠩᠭᠣᠯ'),
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    ),
  );

  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  await expectLater(
    find.byType(MaterialApp),
    matchesGoldenFile('golden-file.png'),
  );
});
```

Is there any way to fix this?

I've read these two articles about golden tests:

- [Flutter: Golden tests — compare Widgets with Snapshots](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-golden-tests-compare-widgets-with-snapshots-27f83f266cea)
- [Do you see the difference? — Flutter Snapshot test](https://medium.com/flutter-community/do-you-see-the-difference-flutter-golden-files-a1d431ed8a69)

Comment: Did you find a solution, @Suragch ?

Comment: @SebastianRoth, No, the best I could do was see if the rendered text size changed using a widget test.

Answer (score 6):

Flutter tests only support one font currently, ahem.

Try out this package from eBay: https://pub.dev/packages/golden_toolkit

Answer (score 3):

Since version `0.2.0-dev` of the package you have access to the method `loadAppFonts()` to automatically load font assets from the `pubspec.yaml` or any package your projects depends on.

[source](https://pub.dev/packages/golden_toolkit/changelog#020-dev)

> ### 0.2.0-dev
>
> Improved the mechanism for loading font assets. Consumers no longer
> need to supply a directory to read the .ttf files from.
>
> They can now simply call: `await loadAppFonts()` and the package will
> automatically load any font assets from their pubspec.yaml or from any
> packages they depend on.

Now your test might look like this:

```dart
testWidgets('Text renders', (tester) async {
  // Load fonts
  await loadAppFonts();

  // Pump your test widget
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Text('My text'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  // Compare image file
  await screenMatchesGolden(tester, 'golden-file');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like real fonts are not supported, yet.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/testing-custompaint-widgets-in-flutter-using-golden-image-files-889fe3bdf9ca

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your widget is composed this is difficult to answer, but I would guess that you are using a RichText widget underneath. If thats the case then adding the fontFamily explicitly to each TextSpan's textStyle should do the trick.