# How to load custom font correctly in this flutter test?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method in my `cubit` that captures a widget as an image and I am testing this method. Long story short this method calls `_captureFromWidget` (see below, the code is copied from package [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)), which accepts the `Widget` and returns a `Uint8List`. (**I am not testing that the package works correctly, I am testing that my method and its parameters work correctly**).

The problem is, that in real app the widget is captured correctly, but in the test, the font of all the `Text` widgets is not rendered correctly, and boxes are shown instead of letters.

I know the reason of this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104547/how-to-check-font-text-on-flutter-golden-test), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447898/flutter-widget-test-cannot-emulate-different-screen-size-properly).

I tried loading the font as they suggested:

in pubspec.yaml:

```
  assets:
    - assets/fonts/
```

and I have in the `assets/fonts` folder my font: `AbrilFatface-Regular.ttf`

in my test:

```
      final Future<ByteData> abrilFatFaceFontData = rootBundle.load('assets/fonts/AbrilFatface-Regular.ttf');
      final FontLoader fontLoader = FontLoader('AbrilFatFace-Regular')..addFont(abrilFatFaceFontData);
      await fontLoader.load();

     Text text = ...; // text that uses custom font from above
     cubit.captureWidget(...); // will invoke _captureFromWidget
```

but still, boxes are shown instead of letters in the captured image:
[image]
this is the result of calling the same methods with the same arguments from the real app:
[image]

### So how to provide the font to the test correctly?

Here is the code that captures the widget:

```
  /// [context] parameter is used to Inherit App Theme and MediaQuery data.
  Future<Uint8List> _captureFromWidget(
    widgets.Widget widget, {
    required Duration delay,
    double? pixelRatio,
    widgets.BuildContext? context,
  }) async {
    // Retry counter
    int retryCounter = 3;
    bool isDirty = false;

    widgets.Widget child = widget;

    if (context != null) {
      // Inherit Theme and MediaQuery of app
      child = widgets.InheritedTheme.captureAll(
        context,
        widgets.MediaQuery(data: widgets.MediaQuery.of(context), child: child),
      );
    }

    final RenderRepaintBoundary repaintBoundary = RenderRepaintBoundary();

    Size logicalSize = ui.window.physicalSize / ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
    Size imageSize = ui.window.physicalSize;

    assert(logicalSize.aspectRatio.toPrecision(5) == imageSize.aspectRatio.toPrecision(5));

    final RenderView renderView = RenderView(
      window: ui.window,
      child: RenderPositionedBox(alignment: Alignment.center, child: repaintBoundary),
      configuration: ViewConfiguration(
        size: logicalSize,
        devicePixelRatio: pixelRatio ?? 1.0,
      ),
    );

    final PipelineOwner pipelineOwner = PipelineOwner();
    final widgets.BuildOwner buildOwner = widgets.BuildOwner(
        focusManager: widgets.FocusManager(),
        onBuildScheduled: () {
          ///
          ///current render is dirty, mark it.
          ///
          isDirty = true;
        });

    pipelineOwner.rootNode = renderView;
    renderView.prepareInitialFrame();

    final widgets.RenderObjectToWidgetElement<RenderBox> rootElement = widgets.RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter<RenderBox>(
        container: repaintBoundary,
        child: widgets.Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          child: child,
        )).attachToRenderTree(
      buildOwner,
    );
    // Render Widget
    buildOwner.buildScope(
      rootElement,
    );
    buildOwner.finalizeTree();

    pipelineOwner.flushLayout();
    pipelineOwner.flushCompositingBits();
    pipelineOwner.flushPaint();

    ui.Image? image;

    do {
      // Reset the dirty flag
      isDirty = false;

      image = await repaintBoundary.toImage(pixelRatio: pixelRatio ?? (imageSize.width / logicalSize.width));

      // This delay should increase with Widget tree Size
      await Future.delayed(delay);

      // Check does this require rebuild
      if (isDirty) {
        // Previous capture has been updated, re-render again.
        buildOwner.buildScope(
          rootElement,
        );
        buildOwner.finalizeTree();
        pipelineOwner.flushLayout();
        pipelineOwner.flushCompositingBits();
        pipelineOwner.flushPaint();
      }
      retryCounter--;
      //retry until capture is successful
    } while (isDirty && retryCounter >= 0);

    final ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

    return byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

Comment: I am curious how did you create the code for capturing? I need to capture widgets to pass image to PDF and now I forced to place such widgets in `Stack` and wrap them into `RepaintDoundary`. But I see your approach is more nice.

Comment: @BambinoUA this code is from an [open-source project I was working on](https://github.com/Haidar0096/Image-Editor-Desktop/tree/master/lib/services/screenshot_service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was doing everything correctly except one thing.

The line `final FontLoader fontLoader = FontLoader('AbrilFatFace-Regular')..addFont(abrilFatFaceFontData);` will determine the `fontFamily` name that must be used in the `TextStyle` of the `Text` element.

and since I was using `AbrilFatFace` as `fontFamily`, the test was not working.

So the solution is to use in the `fontFamily`, the same name passed to the `FontLoader`, since thats the name the font will be identified with.